# Edit text not receiving text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have tried to solve it for hours but been unable to. What is going on is that I setted this editText, called the layout on the activity, and connect it to my variable on the activity, when you click on the field it opens the visual keyboard, but when you press a key, it takes you to a browser-like search screen, instead of just updating the edittext´s text.

on my xml the editText is:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background = "@drawable/splash"
  android:orientation = "vertical">

  <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/searchEdit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textColorHint="@color/hintGray"
android:textSize="20dp"
android:paddingLeft="50dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
android:background="@drawable/a01_text_box"
android:hint="Hint"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"   />

  <ImageButton 
android:id="@+id/searchButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/a01_boton_buscar"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"  /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

on the activity I do this

```
public class SubscribeActivity {

private EditText searchEdit;
private ImageButton searchButton;
private Context context;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.subscribe_main);

        this.context = this;

        findAndInitViews();

}

protected void findAndInitViews() {
    searchEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchEdit);
    searchButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            String codeText = searchEdit.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, codeText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

}
```

I still can't find a way for it not to happen. Can you help me?

Comment: have you called `setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutFromEditText)` before you are attemting `findViewById(id)`

Comment: yes, updated the code there with everything

Comment: @ArielCapozzoli It seems that you have not extended Activity class and you are trying to use onCreate() method of Activity.

Comment: actually it does extend from an major activity that extends Activity class, but i am not sure if i could post that info, so i deleted the extend before posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first I would suggesting to use the `getApplicationContext()` Method of Activity - instead of casting the Activity down to your Context-Object. Beside you must extend `Activity`. Im wondering that your code is running... But I assume it's an copy and paste mistake.

Your `onCreate(Bundle b)` should be public instead of protected.

If the fault is still there I would comment the code not needed for displaying the EditText. And then step by step including the code back again.

Comment: ok, using the coment advise, found that this happens when there is a progressDialog opened from the starting activity, wich is weird since it finish itself once the intent to this one is completed... I deleted the dialog from that activity, yet didnt find why this problem happens. This solved the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are not actually playing with activities

This is wrong:

```
public class SubscribeActivity
```

It should be something like:

```
public class SubscribeActivity extends Activity
```

Comment: actually it does extend from an major activity that extends Activity class, but i am not sure if i could post that info, so i deleted the extend before posting

Comment: then just clean your project and give a try again

Answer (score 0):

Try it different way.

```
     public class SubscribeActivity extends Activity{

    private EditText searchEdit;
    private ImageButton searchButton;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subscribe_main);

    searchEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchEdit);
    searchButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);    
 }

searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String codeText = searchEdit.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(SubscribeActivity.this, codeText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

  }
 }
```

Please try to do in this way and let me know the result.

Comment: @ArielCapozzoli I have corrected my code plz take a look.And what error you are getting in your logcat.

Comment: thats the thing, the logcat doesnt give any error, it just tries to open the global search, the contact search and location search at the same time...

Comment: @ArielCapozzoli Try to to clean your project by using Project > Clean.And to get logcat follow the step go to 1. Windows >Open Perspective > DDMS  2. Go to device tab and click on your currently running device.You will get the logcat. Hope this help.......